# python beautifulsoup get text of lists within lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I apologize for the weird title. But I truly did my best to describe my question.

I am currently scraping a real estate website using bs4. It all went fine until when one building had several rooms each having different prices.

If I'd gone:

```
monthly=soup.find_all('span',{'class':'cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold'})
```

The results were:

```
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.6万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.6万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.7万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.5万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.4万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.2万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.5万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.5万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.5万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.7万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.5万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.7万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.4万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.3万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7万円</span>]
```

Quite eye squinting. But looking through the list, the list does not distinguish the one building with many rooms. I would like to tie the building with its room and get rid of the nasty html and get only the text.

So I did,

```
for i in range(len(rent)):
    monthly=rent[i].find_all('span',{'class':'cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold'})
```

to get,

```
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.6万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.6万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.7万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.5万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.4万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.2万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.5万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.5万円</span>, <span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.5万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.7万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.5万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.7万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">6.4万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7.3万円</span>]
[<span class="cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold">7万円</span>]
```

This is where I am stuck.
As you can see, there is one list that is longer than the other. It has 4 rooms in 1 building.

```
['6.6万円', '6.6万円', '6.7万円', '6.5万円', '6.4万円', '7.2万円', '7.5万円', '7.5万円', '7.5万円', '6万円', '6.7万円', '6万円', '6.5万円', '6.7万円', '6.4万円', '7.3万円', '7万円']
```

Iterating through it to get texts, leaves me with this.
While my desired output would be something like,

```
['6.6万円', '6.6万円', '6.7万円', '6.5万円', '6.4万円', ['7.2万円', '7.5万円', '7.5万円', '7.5万円'], '6万円', '6.7万円', '6万円', '6.5万円', '6.7万円', '6.4万円', '7.3万円', '7万円']
```

Is it possible to get this result?

1. beautifulsoup gave me a list.
2. cannot .text it right away
3. want to create a list within a list as shown above.

I really appreciate all of your guys help.

**
This is the code I used to iterate, get text and create a list

```py
for ii in range(len(monthly)):
    cleared_monthly=monthly[ii].text
    monthly_list.append(cleared_monthly)   

print(monthly_list)
```

Comment: "Iterating through it to get texts, leaves me with this.". Can you include the code that generates the list please? It might just need slight modification.

Comment: I'll add it in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to call items by index when iterating over a list. Furthermore I suggest checking the length of the lists in `monthly` to see whether it contains only one element or not, if the latter is the case add an extra loop for the sublist.
Using list comprehension that would make:

```
monthly = [i.find_all('span',{'class':'cassetteitem_other-emphasis ui-text--bold'}) for i in rent]
monthly_list = [l[0].get_text() if len(l)==1 else [i.get_text() for i in l] for l in monthly]
```